# RadStudio XE7 unable to Sync to iOS Device

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have an app developed using XE7 that I would now like to test on an iOS device.  I am runing Xcode 6 so cant build to the simulator at all. So I have attempted to run on my iPhone.  I have created the required certificates and provisioning profile and the App builds without a problem. However, whenever I go to run on the iPhone I get a e800002d error.  The unhelpful help file that comes up suggests that I should turn my iPhone off and then back on. Which I have done with exactly the same result.

Anyone else had this issue and found a solution.

Comment: The process of setting up and running your app on your iOS device is covered very thoroughly in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3A_Set_Up_Your_Development_Environment_on_the_Mac_%28iOS%29), as is troubleshooting problems with doing so. Have you followed those instructions *exactly*, step by step?

Comment: Yes. That is the exact page I was following.  If you don't follow it to the bottom of the page it will come up with an error about certificates or provisioning not being set up properly.  The error I am getting is according to Apple an error synching.  The troubleshooting guide tells me to turn my iOS device off and then back on.  Which makes no difference I get the same error.  I did think I need to double check that the iPhone has the correct provisioning profile on it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "console" application on OSX and look for that error in the "All Messages" log. This usually has a better error message and explanation.